# Let $A =[a,b,c,f,g,i], B=[b,f,h]$ and $ C = [a,k,l,m]$ Show that $\backslash$ is not associative

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

Question : Let $A =[a,b,c,f,g,i], B=[b,f,h]$ and $ C = [a,k,l,m]$

Show that $\backslash$ is not associative by comparing $(A \backslash B) \backslash C$ with the set $A \backslash(B \backslash C)$.

My attempt: We need to prove that $ \backslash $ is not associative.

Let $A =[a,b,c,f,g,i]$ and $ B=[b,f,h]$

Then $ A \cap B = [b,f]$ are the elements in A and B, $A =[a,c,g,i]$ are the elements in $A$, and $B =[h]$ are the elements in $B$

By definition 3.3.1, the complement definition of B relative to A, written $A \backslash B$ is the set $[x:x \in A \land x \notin B]$

Therefore, for $A \backslash B$, $A =[a,c,g,i]$.

Suppose we have $ A \backslash C$. Then, $[a] = A \cap C$ are the elements in A and C, $A=[c,g,i]$ are the elements in A and $ C = [k,l,m]$  are the elements in C. By complement definition, $A \backslash C$

$A \cap C =[x: x \in A \land x \notin C]$

we have $A =[c,g,i]$

For, $A \backslash(B \backslash C)$.Since there aren't any elements in common for $ B \backslash C$ We need to consider the complement definition

$B \cap C =[x: x \in B \land x \notin C]$

The result would be $ B = [b,f,h]$

Now suppose we have $ A \backslash B$. Then $ [b,f] = A \cap B$ are the elements in A and B, $ [a,c,g,i] = A$ are the elements in A and $[h]=B$ is the only element in B. By taking the complement definition of $ A \cap B$

$A \cap B =[x: x \in A \land x \notin B]$

we have

$[a,c,g,i] = A$

We have proven that $ \backslash $ isn't associative because $A \backslash(B \backslash C)$ has an extra element, so $ [c,g,i] \neq [a,c,g,i]$

Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bit of a a long way round, but you do get there. You don't need to involve any intersections. Just perform the operations on the given sets:

For (A\B)\C first form the set A\B (as you did) and then its complement with C

A\B = {a,b,c,f,g,i} \ {b,f,h} = {a,c,g,i}

**(A\B)\C** = {a,c,g,i} \ {a,k,l,m} = **{c,g,i}**

For A \ (B\C) first form B\C and then its complement with A.

B\C = {b,f,h} \ {c,g,i} = {b,f,h} (i.e. = B because there are no elements in common)

**A\ (B\C)** = {a,b,c,f,g,i} \ {b,f,h} = **{a,c,g,i}**

So you have then demonstrated that **(A\B)\C $\ne $ A\ (B\C)**

Comment: I thought so because I could just straight up use complement definitions everywhere until I see that they aren't equal to each other. It's just that I'm afraid of leaving something out ...

Comment: Better to be a bit longer and right than take shortcuts and be wrong. Confidence grows with practice.